# Reloading Particular Row of PickerView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, reloaddata, uipickerviewdelegate

I have a pickerView consisting of a label and image. i'm updating that image when pickerview is tapped on that particular. but to show the change of image i have to reload pickerView. and when i reload it goes back to the first row. is there any way to reload only that particular row of pickerView?

Code:

```
if selectedRows.contains(contactPerson.text!) {
                      FilteredQuestion_Images[row] = UIImage(named: "Unchecked Checkbox-26")!
                    let image = FilteredQuestion_Images[row]
                    imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

                    if let itemToRemoveIndex = selectedRows.index(of: contactPerson.text!) {
                        selectedRows.remove(at: itemToRemoveIndex)
                        ContactPersons_Multiple.remove(at: itemToRemoveIndex)
                    }

                    self.dropdownPicker.reloadAllComponents()

                }else {


                    selectedRows.append(contactPerson.text!)
                    self.imageName = "Checked Checkbox-26"

                    FilteredQuestion_Images[row] = UIImage(named: "Checked Checkbox-26")!

                    let image = FilteredQuestion_Images[row]
                    imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

                    self.dropdownPicker.reloadAllComponents()

                    }
                }
```

Code of ViewForRow:

```
     func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
  let customeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.dropdownPicker.rowSize(forComponent: 0).width, height: 30))

            // for label
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: customeView.frame.width - 35, height: 30))
            label.textAlignment = .left

            label.text = self.ContactPers[row]

            if FilteredContactsSelected == true {
                label.text = FilteredContactsNames[row]
            }


            let image = FilteredQuestion_Images[row]//UIImage(named: imageName)
            imageView = UIImageView(image: image)



            imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: self.dropdownPicker.rowSize(forComponent: 0).width - 36 , y: 0, width: 26, height: 26)

            customeView.addSubview(imageView!)
            customeView.addSubview(label)//pickerLabel)

            return customeView//pickerLabel
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such system method. However, if you are using custom view, you can try something like this:

```
(pickerView.view(forRow: <#T##Int#>, forComponent: <#T##Int#>) as? MyCustomView).image = newImage
```

Edit:

First you need you need to add view tags to your custom view elements(you can define two constants for this):

```
label.tag = 10
imageView.tag = 20
```

And after a selection occurs, you need to refresh your view's state. You can do that by:

```
if let myView = pickerView.view(forRow: row, forComponent: 0) as? UIView,
        let label = myView.viewWithTag(10) as? UILabel,
        let imageView = myView.viewWithTag(20) as? UIImageView{

        label.text = FilteredContactsNames[row]
        imageView.image = ilteredQuestion_Images[row]
}
```

Comment: where to call this exactly?

Comment: Have you implemented `optional public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView` method of `UIPickerViewDelegate` ?

Comment: Yes i'm using it.

Comment: I have updated my Codeof ViewForRow in the question above please can you guide me with a code how to do that?

Comment: Hi, I am gonna update my answer with some more detailed explanation and code samples in a few minutes.

Comment: Okay Waiting. Thanks!!

Comment: Answer updated, I stay tuned in, should you encounter any issues.

Comment: Where should i use the last chunk of code of yours? in ViewForRow method or in pickerTapped?

Comment: You can implement `UIPickerViewDelegate` method `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)`

Comment: It is still going upwards and then crashing :|

Comment: Got it!! Thanks Alottt :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to update a cell in a PickerView called ColumnPicker, here a simple solution:

```
// declare a ViewController variable
var selectedRowNo : Int!
                
// In didselect(), set the row number
selectedRowNo = row
                
// repaint cell to visualize the change. Call in didSelect() or similar action.
                    
    self.columnPicker.dataSource = self
    self.columnPicker.selectRow(selectedWherePos, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    // call the function pickerView() to update the cell.
    self.pickerView(self.columnPicker, didSelectRow: selectedWherePos, inComponent: 0)
```